# API Error: Wrong number of dashboardFilterColumns 1 instead of 2

Tags: metadata-api, dashboard, jsforce

I'm trying to use the metadata API to move a dashboard from one Salesforce to another, and I'm getting the error

> Wrong number of dashboardFilterColumns 1 instead of 2

The dashboard does have 2 filters, but not all the reports do.  It works fine on the original Salesforce though so I don't think this should be an issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the exact same issue.  I was using the copado click deploy tool to deploy a dashboard and got the error "Wrong number of dashboardFilterColumns 1 instead of 2" when validating the deployment.

In my particular case, the issue was because one of my source reports does not have access to the particular field I was using for one of the filter drop downs.

As a workaround solution, I temporarily removed the component with the problematic source report from the dashboard and then re-validated the deployment. The deployment went through without any issues and then I just re-added that one component to the dashboard in the target environment.